# How can I locate Start button using python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I wanted to locate Start button , I used:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Start')]").click()
```

From this HTML:

```
<div style="height: 34px; width: 356px; overflow: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 24px;"><div style="float: left; margin-left: 290px;"><div tabindex="0" class="v-button v-button-primary primary" role="button" aria-pressed="false"><span class="v-button-wrap"><span class="v-button-caption">Start</span></span></div></div></div>
```

It does not give any console error but also does not click on the start button

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `css` selector with `driver.find_element_by_css_selector`:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.v-button-caption").click()
```

Edit: try clicking on the parent `div[role="button"]`:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.v-button.v-button-primary.primary").click()
```

Comment: Thank you ! but even this didnt work.. Same no Console error but also didnt click on start button

Comment: @Ket Please see my recent edit. You might want to try clicking on the `div` with `role="button"`

Comment: Hi, can you please write full sentense with role= button ? sorry I am new to this

Comment: I wonder, why its not giving any console error , if its not finding an element

Comment: @Ket What is the result for you if you run `print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.v-button.v-button-primary.primary"))`?

Comment: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="76b87eddd18b0791f0ced1fba9212386", element="4f67dbd6-86e3-4f90-8c07-07ef78bbc543")>        this is output

Comment: What is the result when you do `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.v-button.v-button-primary.primary").click()`?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.v-button.v-button-primary.primary").click()      This dosnt give any console error but the button is not clicked

Comment: @Ket After running `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.v-button.v-button-primary.primary").click()` is the button on the page successfully clicked?

Comment: Can we talk over the zoom or something ? so that i can show you my code ? i guess its easier this way ?

Comment: @Ket It would be most helpful if you could paste your code in your post

Comment: <div style="height: 34px; width: 356px; overflow: hidden; padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 24px;"><div style="float: left; margin-left: 290px;"><div tabindex="0" class="v-button v-button-primary primary" role="button" aria-pressed="false"><span class="v-button-wrap"><span class="v-button-caption">Start</span></span></div></div></div>

Comment: @Ket unfortunately the link is not accessible for me. Can you try `driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("div.v-button.v-button-primary.primary").click()')`?

Comment: Again same , no console error but the button is not clicked

Comment: Is it possible to connect through other way ?

Comment: @Ket Can you post a screenshot of the button? It might be in a disabled or otherwise unclickable state.

Answer (score 0):

can you check with this as element lies in the span, so can be identified

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Start']")
```

Try to perform clicking on the element by `using execute_script`

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
```

Comment: nope, it didnt sorry ! also no console error

Comment: can you share the url

Comment: @Ket I've updated my answer can you check

Comment: http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/swee-portal/web-portal#POS-SERVER_CASH_MANAGEMENT__S.01100202304.00

Comment: @Ket can try my updated answer using execute_script()

Answer (score 0):

First check if button is in inside any frame or not. If it is in frame just switch to it before Click on button.
If not please use css selector "div.v-button-primary"

Subbarao
https://youtube.com/channel/UCLVZEaH5jIFbZkFAKCg9keg